# how do I format my dataframe for multiclass svm

Tags: python, pandas, svm

I have a huge dataframe that I want to run a multi class svm model on but I am confused on how to format the dataframe to do so. This is what the dataframe looks like:

| x | y | class |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x1 | y1 | 1 |
| x2 | y2 | 2 |
| x3 | y3 | 3 |
| x4 | y4 | 4 |
| etc | etc | etc |

How do I actually run the data on an svm model? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do this

```
X=df[['x','y']]
Y=df[['class']]
```

After this you will have columns x and y in X and column 'class' in Y you may split data further into X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test by using split function in sklearn library and you the implement SVM using the library of your choice and do the follow up procedures.

Refer to this link for more information on implementing [SVM](https://analyticsindiamag.com/understanding-the-basics-of-svm-with-example-and-python-implementation/)

Comment: Thanks. Does this svm model work for more than 2 classifiers?

Comment: yes it does sklearn is a standard library for mostly all machine learning models and if at all it doesn't support for your current form of data search for blogs there are many blogs which will help you.

Comment: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html this blog will help you

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import svm
df=pd.read_excel('Enter location of your dataset')
features=df[['x','y']]
classes=df[['class']]
clf = svm.SVC(features,classes)
clf.fit(X, y)
```

Comment: great answer sir short and compact